# Gnucash: Keyboard shortcut to move to blank transaction?

Tags: gnucash

When entering transactions in Gnucash, there is a toolbar icon to jump to "Move to the blank transaction at the bottom of the register".  What is the equivalent keyboard shortcut to do that?

Comment: FWIW, the software in question, GnuCash, is a financial management tool.  As a consequence, perhaps this kind of question ought to be on-topic? Discuss at: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-questions-on-the-technical-usage-of-a-financial-management-tool-be-on-topi

Comment: Reopened based on the support at meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd>; my previous attempts to use it didn't work, so I must have been in a different state in my initial attempts.