# Gnucash: Add new column for bookings

Tags: gnucash

Is there a way to add a custom column for accounts in gnucash, so that I can add special information to bookings like: "Who added the entry?" or "What is the date of the bill?"

I could input this information to the "description" field, but that makes it impossible to filter/sort etc.

Comment: I was unsure if this is the right SE site to ask this, but this topic seems to be valid here so I thought I give it a try: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/gnucash-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-to-blank-transaction

Comment: I think it's on topic, but you're more likely to get a good answer by asking on the gnucash list: https://lists.gnucash.org/mailman/listinfo/gnucash-user

Comment: You may get a better answer on SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable View->Double Line, a notes field will become visible with each transaction. You could use that additional field for such information.

It is unfortunately not possible to add custom columns yourself.

Answer copied from same question posted by same user on Gnucash.

http://gnucash.1415818.n4.nabble.com/Add-new-column-for-bookings-td3545734.html